# Use of foreign key relationships in a Viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm

Trying to understand the use of foreign key relationships in viewmodels, but struggling to get anywhere with it. We have three tables, `tblInventory`, `tblLocations` and `tblEquipment`.

Inventory has `LocationID`, which is a foreign key to `tblLocation` and `EquipmentID`, which links to `tblEquipment`.

The foreign key for `LocationID` should display the property of "Location Name", whilst `EquipmentID` should display "Equipment Type".

For a single table, I can do the controller easily enough, however, I can only get the ID numbers for each property when trying to do this through foreign keys.

The following is the **inventory view model**:

```
public class InventoryIndexViewModel
{
    public int InventoryID { get; set; }
    public string StationReference { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public long LocationID { get; set; }

    public List<tblLocation> Locations { get; set; }
    public List<tblEquipment> Equipment { get; set; }
}
```

The **location** viewmodel:

```
public class LocationViewModel
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

And the **equipment** viewmodel:

```
public class EquipmentViewModel
{
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }
    public string Equipment { get; set; }
}
```

And then the **controller**:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var TheInventory = InventoryContext.tblInventories.ToList();

        List<InventoryIndexViewModel> viewModelList = TheInventory
            .Select(u => new InventoryIndexViewModel
            {
                InventoryID = u.InventoryID,
                StationReference = u.StationReference,
                LocationID = u.tblLocation.LocationID,
                EquipmentID = u.tblEquipment.EquipmentID
            }).ToList();
        return View(viewModelList);
    }
```

I'm sure what I'm doing is either miles off, or close but not quite there. Is it the way that I'm connecting the viewmodels? Or is the controller completely off point?

Thanks

Comment: Your view model should contain `public List<LocationViewModel> Locations { get; set; }` and `public List<tblEquipment> Equipment { get; set; }` (not `EquipmentID` and `LocationID`

Comment: Thanks for that, have updated the ViewModel. How do I go about using that on my controller? I have tried `                   Locations = u.tblLocation.LocationID,
                    Equipment = u.tblEquipment.EquipmentID` but am getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type int to system.collections.generic.list" error

Comment: Do your data models contain virtual properties for the collections? Best guess is you want `Locations = u.tblLocation.Select(l => new LocationViewModel() { LocationID = l.LocationID, Location = l.Location Name }),` (ditto for equipment)

Comment: Have never used Virtual Properties, at least not where I can remember. Will have a look into them and see where I get. I don't get a .Select clause on u.tblLocation for example

Comment: Yep, we have the EDMX with the entities stored on it etc, and then Viewmodels

Comment: @Carsten it is mine, but I'm still learning the language so getting easily confused between what I should and shouldn't be doing at certain points.

Comment: well sorry then - it's just that the posted code looks good - and the type error is really obvious

Comment: @Carsten I'm comfortable with using viewmodels on their own, IE, no relationships to another table. It's viewmodels with foreign keys that I don't understand